# Camel Kafka sink connector configuration and dependencies

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect, azure-data-lake

I am trying to use the '*camel-azure-storage-datalake-kafka-connector*' to connect from Kafka to Azure ADLS Gen2

I have a Linux box running Docker with the debezium/zookeeper, debezium/kafka and debezium/connect images.
Picking up changes from the cdc tables with the debezium connector works a treat so I have topics with messages in.

From here I am trying to use the Camel sink connector for ADLS Gen2 to move these messages into Azure. I am very new to Camel, but from what I can see from the connector documentation, I can download the connector as a package, unzip it into my plugin path, add a small section of code into a pom.xml file, and then it should be good to go. But, I do not have a pom.xml file, I have not built a package for this at all so far, so my questions are:

1. Is a pom.xml required if I want to use any of the camel connectors?
2. If so, what is the best way to do this for my particular use case?

Comment: The Camel connectors are plugins for Kafka Connect, not a Java project dependency that needs built

Comment: Got it, so they should all just work then. Thanks!